# I am getting mail afrer Clicking Forgot Password, but after clicking the password reset link I m getting a blank page

Tags: email, password

Forget Password link not loading layout and template page.

Comment: Have you tried turning Developer mode on? In Index.php lines 69-72, change to:

```#if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {```

   ```Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);```

```#}```

```ini_set('display_errors', 1);```

This should show any errors your having on the page, alternatively, check your log files, var/logs/system.log and var/log/exception.log. 

Paste the error onto your question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears on themes after SUPEE-6788

Go to app/design/your/theme/layout/customer.xml

And replace

customer_account_resetpassword

With

customer_account_changeforgotten

Alternative way is backup and remove the customer.xml to let magento uses its base xml.

Please check also register and newsletter subscribe form that works properly. 
Do a research what you have to check after this patch to avoid further inconvenience in the future.